# Jquery listener for clicking a class, but not working when clicking the icon inside it

Tags: javascript, jquery

First of all, I couldn't find this question over here, so I don't know if it has been answered yet.

I have a listener for all the clicks in my site, and then calls a function that checks if the target has the class "wave". If so, it displays a wave effect.

I have tiles with this class, and it works fine, except they have large icons, and if you click them, it does not recognise it as a target with the class.

I tried to put all the tiles inside a div with the class, but somehow it does not recognise it as a target with this class either (I'm assuming it recognize as clicking the target inside them).

I tried to put the 'true' at the end of the listener, in case the bubbling direction could help me, but it didn't.

Any idea? thanks in advance and sorry for my ignorance.

jsfiddle

```
    <div class="tile-container">
  <div class="tile efecteona">
   <h3 class="titol-tile">Gràfics</h3>
   <i class="fa fa-bar-chart tile-icon "></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

"efecteona" would be "wave" class
    https://jsfiddle.net/qtLvef8o/2/

Comment: Code please. Better yet, a http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Could you add the icons as background images for the tiles using CSS?

Comment: I can't add them as background because they get bigger when hover and have different properties depending on the tile. I'm working on a jsfiddle, i'll have it in a minute, thanks

Comment: Edit done. Notice that by clicking the tile you get the effect, but when click the icon you don't.

Comment: You're assuming that target is the tile element when in fact it's the icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the other answers note, the `target` returns the actual clicked element which in this case is the icon and not the div with the class.

Since you use jQuery though, why not use its delegate syntax which allows for this ?

```
$(document).on('click', '.efecteona, button', addOnaEffect);
```

and set `target = this` inside your hander.

updated demo at https://jsfiddle.net/qtLvef8o/4/

Comment: That's a good point. As long as the OP is using jQuery he should utilize as much of it as possible to improve readability and performance.

Comment: I just noticed that puting the div inside an <a> tag it does not redirect me with your solution. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

When you are asking about the e.target it gets the i element, and the i element doesn't have the class you need and neither had the tagname button.

Add this `console.log(target);` next to your line `var target = e.target;` and you will see what I'm saying.

Comment: I know that, and that's my point. I want to get the div element when I click the icon. Or whatever as long as clicking anywhere in the tile it does the wave efect in the entire div

Comment: Then use the closest  method as @imoses said.

Answer (score 0):

When you click an element the event bubbles all the way up to the document, while the target is always the element which initialized it. In your case, it seems that your code assumes the `target` is a tile element, while in fact it can also be the icon element.

Since you tagged on the question that you are using jQuery, there's a simple solution. Use jQuery [closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) method.

```
var target = $(e.target).closest('.efecteona, button').get(0);
```

**[Code example](https://jsfiddle.net/qtLvef8o/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

The `target` is wrong is this case.

I tried to explain by resetting the target when it's the parent that has the class (a bit dirty, can be optimised / better written but it's just to explicitly show the target issue)

https://jsfiddle.net/OxyDesign/wbxvqt2b/1/